# Get Parent id in child schema in graphql django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, graphql, graphene-python

I want to get a child class object in parent schema.

Here's my Models.py

```
class Team(DefaultFieldsModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class Event(DefaultFieldsModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    team = models.foreignkey(Team)

class Bet(DefaultFieldsModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.foreignkey(Event)
```

Schema.py

```
class TeamType(DjangoObjectType):
    home = graphene.Field(TeamType)
    class Meta:
        model = Team

    def resolver_home(self, info):
        **# Here I want to get Bet object and perform some operations**
        if team.bet_id ==2:
            print("bet")   
        return team.bet

Class BetType(DjangoObjectType):
    home_team = graphene.Field(TeamType)

    class Meta:
        model = Bet

    def resolver_home_team(self, info):
      return self.event.team
```

In TeamType schema I want bet object so I can perform operations. 
I have also tried with graphene.String() but it didn't help.

Comment: Your resolve function should be in the format `resolve_<field_name>`.  Also, there isn't a one-to-one relationship between teams and bets. Do you want to get all of the bets for all of the events of a team?